# Check for existence of ID before deleting the record in C# and MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am a new C# and MS Access user, I am making a car insurance program. When trying to delete users, the ID is inserted and the delete process is carried out normally. However, if an ID which does not exist is entered, the program still says "record deleted". This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete?", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;


                string q = "delete from Users where ID=" + numericUpDown1.Value.ToString();
                deletedata(q);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
                numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
                con.Close();
            }
            else
                Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }


    private void deletedata(String q)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = q;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** you are displaying the `Records Deleted` Message without checking the Query execution `status`.

**Solution:**  `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the `int` value to represent `total number` of rows `updated/deleted/inserted` when executed, so you can display `success` message only when return value is `greater than` 0 otherwise display `failure/error` message.

Try This :

```
       int rowsDeleted=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       if(rowsDeleted>0)
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
       else
            MessageBox.Show("No Record to Delete");
```

Comment: Your answer always gives me: Record Deleted, in both cases

Comment: @user3080796: it means it is deleting the record allways, try to give non existing ID to verify.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it always says: No Record To Delete

Comment: @user3080796: take the status into `int` variable ,see my edited answer, it works perfectly:)

Comment: The value of cmd.executenonquery() is always 0 for some reason

Comment: @user3080796: did you try with above updated solution? and also please check wether record exists or not before deleting

Comment: It worked now, HUGE thanks! Please forgive my noobness as I am new to development in general.

Answer (score 0):

If your database has tables in relation with other tables I advise you to not delete but add a field called for exemple "deleted" so you will trace the deleted file.

Because deleting a field can cause an instability in your database if deleted field has relation with other tables.